# Можно ли считать "Гребенщиков — о Цое" эллиптическим предложением?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, цитата

> Гребенщиков — о Цое: "Виктор был..."

"Гребенщиков — о Цое" — это эллиптическое предложение? Или это вовсе не предложение (т. к. нет предикативности), а просто подпись к цитате?