# Эллиптические предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Малышева — о пользе правильного питания: "Нужно..."
>   Гребенщиков — о Цое: "Я считаю..."

Первые части заголовков — это эллиптические предложения? Или это спорные синтаксические конструкции, которые не принято считать предложениями?

Comment: Вы уже задавали такой вопрос: "Можно ли считать “Гребенщиков — о Цое” эллиптическим предложением?" https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444304/Можно-ли-считать-Гребенщиков-о-Цое-эллиптическим-предложением. Пока, к сожалению, он не имеет решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это эллиптические предложения, так как в них отсутствует глагол-сказуемое. Восстановление в предложении глагола-сказуемого не требуется, смысл ясен. Подробно здесь:

[Понятие об эллиптических предложениях](https://studfiles.net/preview/2682314/)  Эллиптическими называются самостоятельно употребляемые предложения особого типа, спецификой структуры которых является отсутствие глагольного сказуемого, причем сказуемого, не упомянутого в контексте, т.е. в смысловом отношении не являющегося необходимым для передачи данного сообщения...

Эти предложения не нуждаются ни в контексте, ни в ситуации, для того чтобы составить представление о действии или состоянии.